# Cross compiling from Fedora 27

Tags: c++, cross-compilation, fedora

I'm attempting to cross-compile a C++11 project for my Raspberry pi. In my searching online, I have come to the conclusion that I need the `g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf` compiler (please correct me if I am wrong here). I am running Fedora 27 on my host machine, and I can only find how to install it on Ubuntu systems. The closest I came was with this install command: `sudo dnf install arm-linux-gnueabihf-{binutils,gcc,glibc}`, and this was the output:

`No match for argument: arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils
No match for argument: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
No match for argument: arm-linux-gnueabihf-glibc
Error: Unable to find a match`

If someone could point me to the correct compiler to download to accomplish this it would be appreciated. This is my first time cross-compiling anything, so feel free to correct me anywhere that I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Try installing:

```
sudo dnf install binutils-arm-linux-gnu gcc-arm-linux-gnu glibc-arm-linux-gnu
```

[`binutils-arm-linux-gnu`](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/27/x86_64/b/binutils-arm-linux-gnu-2.29-3.fc27.x86_64.html) contains the GNU binutils for the `arm-linux-gnu` target. [`gcc-arm-linux-gnu`](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/27/x86_64/g/gcc-arm-linux-gnu-7.1.1-3.fc27.x86_64.html) contains GCC set up for cross compiling to ARM — but note that *"Only building kernels is currently supported.  Support for cross-building
user space programs is not currently provided as that would massively multiply
the number of packages."*

[`glibc-arm-linux-gnu`](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/27/x86_64/g/glibc-arm-linux-gnu-2.26-1.fc27.noarch.html) contains the GNU C library. The discussion on [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1456209) may be relevant regarding the kernel only restriction.

Comment: This MAY solve the problem, but you should explain what it does and how this addresses the problem.

Comment: Something to be wary of here is that the OP does not state which model of Pi this is applicable to.  AFAIK, current distro cross-compilers target ARMv7+,  meaning no good for the single core models, including the Pi Zero (W).

Comment: It's a Rasperry Pi 3. @goldilocks

Comment: I have since found a way to avoid the need to cross compile to the pi (I compile on the pi itself), so I'm not sure if this works or not and do not have a way to test it currently, since I've changed some things in my project. If someone else can vouch for it solving the problem, I will accept it.

Comment: Unless you have something that just plain takes too long to compile on the pi, and you can't work on it on some other computer because it uses pi specific libs, compiling on the pi (and doing dev work on a big box as much as you can) is the right way to go.  As noted above, putting together all the libs you need to support many userland things with a cross compiler is just too tedious.

Answer (score -1):

try     "dnf install arm-*" as a starter but that fouls up on a 64 bit PC.
I hope it works on 32 bit or at least gives you some helpful hints